# Lipschitz and Holder continuous

Tags: notation, continuity, holder-spaces

Let a function $f(t,x)$, which is Lipshitz continuous in $x$  and $1/2$-Holder continuous in $t$. Is there any "official" and widely accepted way to denote the class of such functions ?

I am thinking of  $\mathbb{C}^{0,\frac{1}{2}}$. Any suggestions on this ?

Comment: Hum...not sure. $C^{0,1/2}$ suggests that $f$ is $1/2$ Holder with respect to $(x,t)$, not $t$. And it does not say anything about the Lipchitzness in $x$ anyway. You could write $f(x,\cdot)\in C^{0,1/2}$ and $f(\cdot, t)\in C^{0,1}$. Unless you mean uniform $|f(x,t)-f(x',t')|\leq C\|x-x'\|\|t-t'\|^{1/2}$.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any "official" notation. Maybe we can take a cue from the generalized Hölder spaces? One notation for generalized Hölder spaces is

$$ f \in C^n_\omega \iff f \in L^\infty \text{ and } \sup_{|y| \leq h}\|\Delta^n_y f\| \leq C \omega(h) $$

where $\Delta^n_y$ is the $n$-th order finite difference operator with step $y$. The usual spaces correspond to $n = 1$ and $\omega(h) = |h|^\alpha$ for some $\alpha$.

By analogy an okay notation would be writing your space as $C^1_\Omega$ where $\Omega = \Omega(\Delta x, \Delta t) = |\Delta x| + \sqrt{|\Delta t|}$ or something like that, and define your seminorm accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would use a notation 
$\mathbb{C^0}  \times  \mathbb{H}^{ \frac{1}{2}}$ because the function has two arguments.